# DearPyGui Проблемы с Кирилицей

Tags: python, dearpygui

[image: П]Проблема в виджете. Открытия директорий и файлов.
Шрифт новый и кириллицу подключил как в руководств по библиотеки в проводнике знаки ????? заменились на правильные имена в Кириице.Но зайти в дирректорию не может. Если открыть скрипт из в составе на пути скрипта будут папки  на кириллеце то на наверху "C:  Users serdy  Pycharms" она может заменить на С Users  ????   Pycharms